# ZipException: transform duplicate entry com/google/android/gms/internal/zzez.class

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, transform

When I try to build APK, there is this message :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/internal/zzez.class

but when I try to debug app this working.

I has delete the .gradle directory but without success.

This is my build.gradle app file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        useNewCruncher false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.DringMe.launcher.fr"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.appspanel.com/appspanel-sdk-android/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.9.0'

        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
       // annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'


        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.github.sd6352051.niftydialogeffects:niftydialogeffects:1.0.0@aar'
        compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0'

        compile files('src/main/libs/edm.jar')
        compile files('src/main/libs/rc.jar')
        compile files('src/main/libs/cdm.jar')
        compile files('src/main/libs/license.jar')
        compile files('src/main/libs/knox.jar')


        compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.3'
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
        compile project(':slideDateTimePicker-release')
        compile 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
        //noinspection GradleDependency
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


        compile project(':AppsPanelSDK')
      //  compile 'com.appspanel.android:sdk:4.4.2'
    }
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'stax'
    compile.exclude group: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SmartAdServer-Android-SDK-6.7.1')
    //    compile project(':AppsPanelSDK')

}
```

I don't know why it does that and I am stuck.

I need to help please!!

Thanks.

Comment: Just a sidenote, some of your dependencies use really old versions, e.g. support library, retrofit, etc.

Comment: upgrade all your libraries to the latest version and also replace compile with implementation

Comment: I try to upgrade all libraries and replace compile by implementataion by it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem more or less:

I replace

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ext.googleServicesVersion = '11.8.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googleServicesVersion"
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit of an explanation on why this should solve the problem stated in the question?